# How can I extract DNA from horse hair?

Tags: dna, hair

For my project I have to find an inexpensive, quick and simple-to-use method to extract DNA from horse hair. The sample does not have to be purified because the sample will be used for LAMP and not PCR.

I will do my internship at a university so most kinds of equipment and materials are available to me. I also have a budget for my project. I searched online for DNA extraction kits but didn't have much luck because many kits were for human hair and horse hair is a little bit thicker.

Does anyone have experience with a method that would work for my case as well and can advise me?

Comment: What kind of equipment and materials do you have access to?

Comment: i will do my internship to the Wageningen university so most kind of equipment and materials are available for me, i also have a budget in terms for helping my project. i did search online to find DNA extraction kits but not that much luck because many kits where for human hair and horse hair is a little bit thicker. Do you know a method that kan help me with this, or perhaps a link where the method is explained ?